# Transaction Management for Shared DB in Microservices

Tags: database, spring, microservices

I have 2 Microservices that using same DB

1. First Microserivce for Balance Management .
2. Second Microserivce for Reservation Management.

And I have the following business scenario:

1. Need to check if the client have balance by calling REST Services from (Balance Management Microservice).
2. If he have balance , then I have to call another REST Services to reserved the balance from (Balance Management Microservice ) .
3. Then I have to do some kind of airline reservation also by calling another REST Service from (Reservation Management).

So the question is how to rollback the step 2 if the step 3 fail by using Transaction Management between REST Services by taking care that all Microservice using same DB

Comment: Could you describe your problem in more detail? Are these separate applications or just 2 instances of the same application? What operations do you need to perform in the transaction?

Comment: I updated the question pleas check.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction is a unit of work which either is %100 successful or %0 successful. The transaction is managed and implemented by the database, not your application. That is why you can scale out an application (create more instances) and your data remains consistent.

Likewise many different applications can talk to the same database, this doesn't matter. Say you are transferring money, which corresponds to 2 rows in a database being updated in the same transaction. Lets say you do it incorrect and create 2 transactions instead to update each row individually. Whether you are running 1 or many applications or instances doesn't matter, if you did this incorrect in 2 transactions then you would risk having inconsistent data, say if another transaction debited an account and there wasn't enough money anymore in-between your transactions, then you might get an account with less than 0 dollars, not good not good.

On another note this has a cost. Transactions are expensive, they take more time, and updates to a row will occur sequentially not at the same time, which is why systems which need to scale to extreme performance sometimes use append only databases / NoSQL and rely on eventual consistency instead.

Answer (score 0):

As usual when we have this kind of issues we should look into existing best practice. In this case, [SAGAs](http://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) design pattern is the answer to your question.